# how did WordNet come in being

Tags: wordnet, nlp

I wonder how the hierarchical relationship in WordNet between the words are retrieved.

Is that manually done or via computer techniques.

If based on computer techniques, what are they?

Comment: A good place to start is probably http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/publications/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the FAQ:

> q.1.2 Where do you get the definitions for WordNet? (short answer) Our
>   lexicographers write them.
>
> Where do you get the definitions for WordNet? (long answer) From the
>   foreword to WordNet: An Electronic Lexical Database, pp. xviii-xix:
>
> People sometimes ask, "Where did you get your words?" We began in 1985
>   with the words in Kučera and Francis's Standard Corpus of Present-Day
>   Edited English (familiarly known as the Brown Corpus), principally
>   because they provided frequencies for the different parts of speech.
>   We were well launched into that list when Henry Kučera warned us that,
>   although he and Francis owned the Brown Corpus, the syntactic tagging
>   data had been sold to Houghton Mifflin. We therefore dropped our plan
>   to use their frequency counts (in 1988 Richard Beckwith developed a
>   polysemy index that we use instead). We also incorporated all the
>   adjectives pairs that Charles Osgood had used to develop the semantic
>   differential. And since synonyms were critically important to us, we
>   looked words up in various thesauruses: for example, Laurence Urdang's
>   little "Basic Book of Synonyms and Antonyms" (1978), Urdang's revision
>   of Rodale's "The Synonym Finder" (1978), and Robert Chapman's 4th
>   edition of "Roget's International Thesaurus" (1977) -- in such works,
>   one word quickly leads on to others. Late in 1986 we received a list
>   of words compiled by Fred Chang at the Naval Personnel Research and
>   Development Center, which we compared with our own list; we were
>   dismayed to find only 15% overlap.
>
> So Chang's list became input. And in 1993 we obtained the list of
>   39,143 words that Ralph Grishman and his colleagues at New York
>   University included in their common lexicon, COMLEX; this time we were
>   dismayed that WordNet contained only 74% of the COMLEX words. But that
>   list, too, became input. In short, a variety of sources have
>   contributed; we were not well disciplined in building our vocabulary.
>   The fact is that the English lexicon is very large, and we were lucky
>   that our sponsors were patient with us as we slowly crawled up the
>   mountain.